# Filter Pandas dataframe by Key+Unique values of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, unique

My pandas dataframe looks something like this:

| Country | Continent | N. of cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Norway | Europe | 163 |
| Norway | Europe | 163 |
| Norway | Europe | 163 |
| Norway | Europe | 18 |
| Norway | Europe | 18 |
| Norway | Europe | 18 |
| Norway | Europe | 27 |
| Norway | Europe | 27 |
| Italy | Europe | 34 |
| Italy | Europe | 34 |
| Italy | Europe | 11 |
| Italy | Europe | 11 |
| Italy | Europe | 11 |

....

I received the file and it had probably been formatted wrongly. Long story short:
I want to filter by country (and continent) and then sum the "N. of cases" but just by unique value, e.g. fo Norway I'd have

N. of cases: 163+18+27=208 :

| Country | Continent | N. of cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Norway | Europe | 208 |
| Italy | Europe | 45 |

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplictes per all 3 columns and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['Country','Continent','N. of cases'])
         .groupby(['Country','Continent'], as_index=False, sort=False)['N. of cases']
         .sum())
```

If only 3 columns:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates()
         .groupby(['Country','Continent'], as_index=False, sort=False)['N. of cases']
         .sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby(['Country','Continent']).apply(lambda dd:dd['N.ofcases']
                                           .drop_duplicates().sum())\
    .rename('N.ofcases').reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for taking the time to answer! This question was asked 7 months ago, and an answer was posted then. If you think your answer adds valuable additional information to the existing answers, please include a description of why your answer is different and useful. To me, it looks very similar to the previous answer. Thanks!